# Updates to Windows 7 on PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates

I have been unable to run windows updates since leaving my company. I believe this was previously done through the VPN. Is there a way to redirect to the Internet directly from home? The PC is it it's own Workgroup and so no dependency on AD, Domains, etc.

Comment: What (if any) error are you getting when trying to update?

Answer (score 1):

Go into Windows Updates, and check if there is a link to "Check for updates from Microsoft" or something to that effect. If there is:

1. Click Start, in the Search bar type `Regedit`
2. Navigate to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`
3. Ensure that `UseWUServer` has a value of 0

Companies often use a WSUS server to manage Windows Updates which is an internal server that computers contact to check for and download updates. If you leave the company the server will be unavailable so you won't be able to check for updates.

Comment: I forgot that you'll need to restart the Windows Update service (or the computer if you don't know how) for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to look into `hosts` file (Open that in notepad or notepad++), and check whether there is any entry for windows update URL.

`%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\`

The url might be something in the line of 
`http://*.download.windowsupdate.com;` . Again I am not sure of the exact url pattern. just check if there are any entries in the hosts file.

Comment: Since when are there URLs in the `hosts` file?